# ASP.NET C# backend, did the user press OK or Cancel from JavaScript confirm box?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, confirm

In the C# backend code for a website, I have the following code that displays a message for the user, enumerating the data they are about to submit, and asking for human-confirmation that the information appears accurate.

This is executed within C#, not within JavaScript, so how can I access the result of the `confirm` function?
My C# logic needs to follow a different path if they click OK, versus if they click Cancel.

I'm working on a very old application (13 years), that has been untouched for quite some time.
As a result, I don't have the ability to alter the general design of the application.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "InvalidEntrySubTypeAlert", "confirm('" +
    "Are you sure you want to create the following deal?\n" +
    "\nDeal ID :\t\t\t" + nDealID +
    "\nCompany Name :\t\t" + txtCompanyName.Text +
    "\nEntry Subject :\t\t" + txtEntrySubject.Text +
    "\nBusiness Lead :\t\t" + ddlBusinessLead.SelectedItem.Text +
    "\nLicense Status :\t\t" + ddlLicenseStatus.SelectedItem.Text +
    "\nEffective Date :\t\t" + string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", calEffectiveDate.SelectedDate) +
    "\nExpiration Date :\t\t" + string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", calExpirationDate.SelectedDate) +
   "\nLicense Location :\t\t" + txtLicenseLocation.Text +
    "\nEntry Sub Type :\t\t" + ddlEntrySubType.SelectedItem.Text.Split(' ')[0]
    + "');", true);
```

Comment: Using StartupScripts is generally a bad idea for interactive content. Would have gone with pure JS and eventually WebMethods for data ...

Comment: You can use a hidden field for that, Javascript is client side and runs before the server call.

Comment: @DevEstacion A hidden field sounds like a good plan. I'll give that a try and see what I can do.

Comment: @Giffyguy tell me if it works for you, so i can post an answer and you can close this question

Comment: @DevEstacion Will do.

Comment: @DevEstacion I won't be able to properly test for probably another week, due to our infrastructure being ancient. However, a hidden field appears to be the correct solution for the time being. Feel free to answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: @Giffyguy answer posted, just added additional details but you prolly have your implementation already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HiddenField` to set the value from the client side and then access it on the Server.

Here is a mockup

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hndSetFromJS" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

And set the value like this

```
document.getElementById("#<%= hndSetFromJS.ClientID %>").value = "yourValue";
```

or

```
$("#<%= hndSetFromJS.ClientID %>").val("yourValue"); // Jquery
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would call a page method (a method in the code behind marked with webmethod attribute) from client side or use ajax to call a web service.

Since the confirm action is executed client side there's no direct link to your server side cide

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 functions in client side

```
function functionOK()
{
//some code
}
function functionCancel()
{
    //some code
}
```

and change your code like this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "InvalidEntrySubTypeAlert", "if(confirm('" +
    "Are you sure you want to create the following deal?\n" +
    "\nDeal ID :\t\t\t" + nDealID +
    "\nCompany Name :\t\t" + txtCompanyName.Text +
    "\nEntry Subject :\t\t" + txtEntrySubject.Text +
    "\nBusiness Lead :\t\t" + ddlBusinessLead.SelectedItem.Text +
    "\nLicense Status :\t\t" + ddlLicenseStatus.SelectedItem.Text +
    "\nEffective Date :\t\t" + string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", calEffectiveDate.SelectedDate) +
    "\nExpiration Date :\t\t" + string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", calExpirationDate.SelectedDate) +
   "\nLicense Location :\t\t" + txtLicenseLocation.Text +
    "\nEntry Sub Type :\t\t" + ddlEntrySubType.SelectedItem.Text.Split(' ')[0]
    + "')){ functionOK();} else{functionCancel()}", true);
```